# How to recover mysql database including passwords?

Tags: mysql

How to recover all the data from mysql database , laptop has been damaged , how to get all the data out of my laptop ?

Comment: Well, you need to salvage whatever data you can in your hard drive first. Make sure it is not completely dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1 : First of all you need to recover your data from laptop

If issue related with other than Hard disk then you can use your hard disk in any laptop with same model to get your data.

If your hard disk is crashed then may be you need some data recovery software.

Step2: If you are able to get your data then copy your mysql data from below directory-

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL SERVER 5.5\DATA\

Note: It is default path for mysql 5.5 may vary as per your configuration and version.

Step3: Now install mysql in your new PC/LAPTOP

Step4: stop mysql service

Step5: Now copy all data from above folder to new server's mysql data directory after excluding .pid ad .err file from old system (after removing old data from here).

Step6: now start mysql service again and check.

Comment: While your instructions might be useful, you have jumped to conclusions for operating system and MySQL version number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try plugging in the laptop HDD to another computer and hopefully you can access the drive as a mapped drive and be able to recover your files.